# Cakephp Controller index link not working without trailing slash

Tags: php, cakephp

(First question on stackoverflow. Tell me what I can do better)

When accessing controllers index pages it is not important if i type a trailing slash or not. Cakephp redirects both versions automaticaly.

Now my 'videos'-controller is behaving weird. It worked fine 2 days ago but now I cannot accessed it without a trailing slash.

Examples:

- domain.com/**users/** -> Working user index site
- domain.com/**users** -> Working user index site
- domain.com/**videos/** -> Working videos index site
- domain.com/**videos/add/** -> Working videos add site
- domain.com/**videos/add** -> Working videos add site
- domain.com/**videos** -> Domain redirects to domain.com/**webroot/videos/** and a MissingControler Exception is thrown. The error message is:

> Error: WebrootController could not be found.
>
> In the case you tried to access a plugin controller make sure you added it to your composer file or you use the autoload option for the plugin.
>
> Error: Create the class WebrootController below in file: src/Controller/WebrootController.php

I have not defined any Routes for Videos. I made no changes to the htaccess files.

Can anyone help me with this error? Should I post additional source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have videos folder inside your webroot directory. Please change folder name or apply a route.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, renamed the folder and that did it. Would have never figured that out myself